# What is the difference between watchOptions.ignored and webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

When using webpack with watch, such as when using `webpack-dev-server` there seem to be (at least) two different ways of excluding files from watching. I can't really find any documentation on the difference between these two configurations and why they are different. Does anyone know why? Is one method preferred? Should I open an issue and/or pull request to improve documentation?

The case I recently ran into where watch was being triggered multiple times on first run was fixed by adding `watchIgnorePlugin` and not fixed by `watchOptions.ignored`

#### webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin

> Ignore the specified files, i.e. those matching the provided paths or regular expressions, while in watch mode.
>
> ```
> new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin(paths)
> ```
>
> **Options**
>
> - paths (array): A list of RegExps or absolute paths to directories or'
>     files that should be ignored.
>
> ---
>
> https://webpack.js.org/plugins/watch-ignore-plugin/

#### watchOptions.ignored

> For some systems, watching many file systems can result in a lot of CPU or 
>   memory usage. It is possible to exclude a huge folder like `node_modules`:
>
> ```
>  ignored: /node_modules/
> ```
>
> It is also possible to use [anymatch](https://github.com/es128/anymatch) patterns:
>
> ```
>  ignored: "files/**/*.js"
> ```
>
> ---
>
> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/

Comment: Hi, @obusk, have you found the answer? I also want to know that.

Comment: @Siou I actually didn't find anytihng about it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

The `WatchIgnorePlugin`-plugin supports a list of RegExps or absolute paths to directories or files that should be ignored.

The `watchOptions.ignored`-option supports [anymatch](https://github.com/micromatch/anymatch)-patterns, which includes regular expression, glob, string, or function that takes the string as an argument and returns a truthy or falsy value.

If you were working on Windows, this might have been the reason why `watchOptions.ignored` didn't work for you:

> Note: This module has Bash-parity, please be aware that Windows-style backslashes are not supported as separators. See https://github.com/micromatch/micromatch#backslashes for more information.